# How to merge two tables in SAS/SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I want to concatenate two datasets using a primary key, in which if a primary key(of first dataset) is not present in second dataset then the second dataset should get concatenate into the first dataset.

Example -
Dataset 1

```
Student R.NO age
Kevin 1. 25
Tom. 2.    26
joe.    3.    24
```

Dataset 2

```
James. 1.  26
Stephnie 4.  21
Alaster.  3.   26
```

Resultant Dataset -

```
Student R.No.  Age
Kevin  1.    25
Tom.    2.   26
Joe.     3.    24
Stephnie 4.  21
```

Here only Stephnie is added in the resultant dataset because her r.no is not present in dataset 1

Comment: What about values in second datasets whose keys are already in the first dataset? Do you ignore those observations? Replace the observations in the first with the observation from the second? Or combine them in some manner?  Do the key values uniquely identify observations in either dataset?

Comment: To make the question clearer show some example input and the desired output.  Also show the code you have tried and explain why it does not do what you want.

Comment: I have added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Dataset1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Dataset2
    WHERE rowno NOT IN (SELECT rowno FROM #TEMP1)
```

Output: [image]

Comment: dont forget to add `proc sql` and `quit;` at the top and bottom

Comment: @Niqua is that a SAS thing? I have been using T-SQL so I'm not used to seeing that syntax.

Comment: yeah, in order to run sql commands in SAS you have to call process named `sql`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
proc sql;
create table dataset3 as 
select * from dataset2 
where r_no not in (select r_no from dataset1)
;quit;

data final;
set dataset1 dataset3;
run;
```